# BullMQ reusing redis connections

Tags: typescript, ioredis, bullmq

I am trying to add logic to re-use redis connections with bullMQ using [this section of the bullMQ docs](https://docs.bullmq.io/bull/patterns/reusing-redis-connections).

I am using the most recent (1.80.6) BullMQ npm version.

From the docs, the expectation is to define the `createClient` method, which is a property of `QueueOptions`.

However, doing so raises an error TS2559.

> Type '{ createClient: (type: string, redisOpts: any); }' has no
> properties in common with type 'QueueOptions'.

Was the `createClient` logic deprecated?if Yes, are there alternatives?

If not, any pointers to what am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `IORedis` instance in as the connection.

```
import IORedis from 'ioredis';
const connection = new IORedis('redis://someredisurl:6379');
const myQueue = new Queue('queue_name', { connection });
```

Comment: will this then use the connection passed in or create a new connection from it. by reading the documentation i thought it was going to create new connection from it. https://docs.bullmq.io/guide/connections